# How does m2e decide if project has java nature?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using a special Maven plugin which provides a custom packaging type and defines a special lifecycle mapping. But it is still a Java-like project so I'd like Eclipse (with m2e plugin) to import the project as a Java project (With java nature in .project file). But it always imports it as a simple project without java nature. I always have to add the java nature to the .project file manually.

I also tried keeping packaging type "jar" and changed the plugin to provide a custom lifecycle mapping for "jar". But still m2e doesn't recognize it as a java project.

So how does m2e decide if it must enable the Java nature in the project or not? Or is there some special m2e configuration I can put into the Maven pom.xml to tell m2e that my project is a java project?

Comment: Have you asked on the m2e mailing list where the experts are?

Comment: I love mailing lists, and indeed the focused expertise is high on a list.  BUT on the other hand, stackoverflow is a much nicer repository of information than mailing lists.  Much better location for community widsom, imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! No need to change the packaging type to "JAR". I only need to include the maven-compiler-plugin in the lifecycle mapping:

```
<!DOCTYPE component-set>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
      <role-hint>custom</role-hint>
      <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
      <configuration>
        <phases>
          <compile>
            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile,
            my.custom.plugin:compile
          </compile>
        </phases>
      </configuration>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

Now m2e adds the java nature to the project when importing it and still executes the custom life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

try adding maven eclipse plugin to your POM file.

> ```
> > <plugin>
> >         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
> >         <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
> >         <version>2.9</version>
> > </plugin>
> ```

Comment: Don't see why this should help. This Maven plugin has nothing to do with m2e. But I tried it anyway. Doesn't help.

Comment: this will structure your application to a format where eclipse understand. first you need to update your pom with what i have given to you. then go to your pom location using your command prompt or shell (if linux). then type $mvn eclipse:eclipse after that, go back to your eclipse project and refresh your project.

Comment: Yes, I know. Using this Maven plugin is a completely different way to use Maven in Eclipse than using the Eclipse plugin m2e. I prefer using m2e so the maven-eclipse-plugin cannot solve my problem.